# Como saber que fuente y tamaño por defecto usa la propiedad Title del método Tk() en python?

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

Alguien puede decirme por favor como hago para **saber que tipo y tamaño de fuente usa por defecto Python en los títulos de sus ventanas**?

Estoy usando tkinter y quiero saber ese dato, para poder usar dicha fuente igual también en mis label y entradas.

Quiero que mis interfaces se vean bien diseñadas, uniformes y profesionales. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Edite y eliminé la última parte de tu pregunta pues la hace lucir basada en opiniones y eso generaría su cierre

Comment: Hola Jose, si quieres utilizar una ventana bien diseñada como dices, te recomiendo utilizar PyQt por ser más completa en temas de deseño.

Comment: Gracias amigos. Entendido.

Answer (score 0):

La fuente de la barra de título no es algo que controle Tkinter y en general cualquier otro framework no específico. La barra de título y los bordes de la ventana son cosa del [gestor de ventanas](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gestor_de_ventanas) de turno usado en el sistema operativo, como `kwin` en KDE Plasma.

El poder o no obtenerla, dependerá del SO y de su gestor de ventanas, en todo caso no hay nada que sea universal, dependerá de llamadas específicas del sistema de turno.

Si quieres un control pleno, la opción suele ser hacer una ventana frameless, sin bordes y sin barra de título y crear una barra desde cero para nuestra ventana usando widgets normales.

Obviamente, perdemos lo que el administrador de ventanas ofrece (botones de maximizado, minimizado, cierre, siempre encima, etc, mover la ventana haciendo click y arrastrando, redimencionado haciendo click en los bordes, etc). Todo ésto, si lo necesitamos deberemos implementarlo por nosotros mismos.

Comment: Ok amigo, gracias, entiendo.